# setting value of string& to string

Tags: c++

I have a string& parameter, and i want to assign it to string parameter.

How can it be done.

Comment: Post some code that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: Do you mean like a function void f(string& a, string b) within which the value of b is assigned to a? Or are you talking about something like string * b as the second parameter, to access that outside f()? Please be clear and supply us with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void f(string &param);

string myString = "something";

f(myString)
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, `string&` or even `const string&` is just a name alias and if you have it somewhere in your code, it's equal to

```
// This means you just create a new ALIAS named "aliased_string"
// for REAL "real_string"
string& aliased_string = real_string;
```

*Now, whenever you make something with your `aliased_string`, the changes are done directly with your `real_string`.*

**Hence, assigning becomes very simple:**

```
// Create a new string
string constructed_string;

// Means the same as "constructed_string = real_string"
constructed_string = aliased_string;
```

Note, that if you have some function with reference in it's parameter list, the logic remains the same:

```
void foo (string& aliased_string) { ... }
```

generally means the same as

```
void foo () { string& aliased_string = real_string }
```

where `real_string` is passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean reassigning a string reference then it cannot be done

```
string &stringref = a_string;

stringref = &b_string; // Cannot be done
```